# how to configure this route for webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have a controller to GET a resource(say, Employee), which has two properties (say, CategoryId and DepartmentId). I need to configure the routes to support the following URLs:

```
~/api/employees/1234 [to get the employee with employeeId=1234]
~/api/employees [to get all the employees]
~/api/employees?departmentid=1 [to get all the employees with departmentId=1]
```

and the controller code looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
{
    ....
}

public IEnumerable<Employee> Get(int employeeId, int departmentId = -1, int categoryId = -1)
{
    .....
}
```

How to configure routes for this controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for any querystyring parameter, there's nothin to do on the routing side: just have the controller method parmater matching with the qs parameter name(case insensitive.)

If instead your method parameter refers to a uri segment, method paramenter name has to match with route parameter/segment between curly brackets

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "/api/{controller}/{employeeId}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

that means you need a controller with following method

```
public class EmployeesController : ApiController
{
public IEnumerable<Employee> Get(int employeeId){...} 
}
```

keep in mind that, unless you use action, on your controller you can only one method per http verb.
In other word your sample having 2 method for the verb get won't work unless you use explicit action for both of them.

Comment: I know that query string parameter has nothing to do with routing. lets say you want another 'Get' action in EmployeesController with the same parameters, something like this: public IEnumerable<Employee> Get(int DepartmentId = 1){....}. How would you configure the route for this action method?

Comment: If you want have different parameter(having a different name as per your sample) read from the same url segment, you need to create 2 different controllers. If you need 2 get within the same controller assign a specific action to each get, but they cannot have same differente parameter name read both from same url segment: you may need querystring for at least one of them, specially for "DepartmentId" makes more sense since the controller has been named "Employees"

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using Attribute routing?  We use Attribute routing extensively now, to the point that we have completely got rid of the default /controller/action type routes that we had with MapHttpRoute.

Instead we decorate our controllers as follows.  Firstly we create a route prefix for the controller so that we know what the base route is that we require

```
/// <summary>   A controller for handling products. </summary>
[RoutePrefix("api/purchasing/locations/{locationid}/products")]
public class ProductsController : PurchasingController
{
```

Then for each action in the controller we decorate it as follows:

```
    [Route("", Name = "GetAllProducts")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllProducts(int locationid, ODataQueryOptions<FourthPurchasingAPI.Models.Product> queryOptions)
    {
        IList<Product> products = this.GetProducts(locationid);
```

and

```
    [Route("{productid}", Name = "GetProductById")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int locationid, string productid)
    {
        Product product = this.GetProductByID(locationid, productid);
```

so a call to [api/purchasing/locations/1/products/](http://myserver.com/api/purchasing/locations/1/products/) will resolve to the route named "GetAllProducts"
and a call to [api/purchasing/locations/1/products/1](http://myserver.com/api/purchasing/locations/1/products/1)  will resolve to the route named "GetProductById"

You could then create another GetProduct action in your controller with the same signature, just set the attribute route appropriately, e.g.

```
    [Route("/department/{departmentId}", Name = "GetAllProductsForDepartment")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllProductsWithDeptId(int locationid, int departmentId)
    {
        IList<Product> products = this.GetProducts(locationid, departmentId);
```

Now a call to  [api/purchasing/locations/1/products/department/1234](http://myserver.com/api/purchasing/locations/1/products/department/1234) will resolve to the route named "GetAllProductsForDepartment"

I know that this example is using Web Api 2, but look at [this link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting.WebApi/) for Attribute Routing in Web Api.  It should be exactly the same instead you will be returning something other than an IHttpActionResult.